# Are Transponder Mode A and C still in use?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, transponder, icao-sarps

Are the ATC transponder Mode A and Mode C still in use (according to ICAO or FAA rules)?

Comment: Mode A+C are still used all over the world. It might be easier to answer if you provide a bit of context and explain why you are asking.

Comment: I can’t find a source but I suspect that Mode A only transponders have not been sold since the mid-1980s (or even earlier) so you aren’t likely to find any currently installed. Mode C transponders all have the ability to turn off the altitude reporting capability if ATC is receiving bad data and act like Mode A transponders. I don’t normally fly where ADSB is required so I’ll keep mine until it stops working.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. According to Title 14 CFR [§91.215   ATC transponder and altitude reporting equipment and use.](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e1875d916d8b892a82ec130336cbfdf5&mc=true&node=se14.2.91_1215&rgn=div8)

Specifically:

> (a) All airspace: U.S.-registered civil aircraft. For operations not
>   conducted under part  121 or 135 of this chapter, ATC transponder
>   equipment installed must meet the performance and environmental
>   requirements of any class of TSO-C74b (Mode A) or any class of
>   TSO-C74c (Mode A with altitude reporting capability) as appropriate,
>   or the appropriate class of TSO-C112 (Mode S).

the use of Mode A or Mode C (e.g.: Mode A with altitude reporting capability) is acceptable for flight under Part 91. That covers all of general aviation (GA), of which a large percentage use Mode A/C transponders.

With the upcoming ADS-B mandate, many GA operators are switching to Mode S to get the 1090 MHz ES ADS-B.  But others are keeping the Mode A/C and adding a 978 MHz UAT to meet the ADS-B requirement. In any case, there are still a large number of Mode A/C transponders in use and likely will be the case for quite a while.

Mode S is optional and only required for operations under Parts 121 (Air Carriers) and 135 (Air Taxi).

For Part 121, a Mode S transponder is required by [§121.356   Collision avoidance system.](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e1875d916d8b892a82ec130336cbfdf5&mc=true&node=se14.3.121_1356&rgn=div8)

For Part 135, Mode S is required by [§135.143   General requirements.](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e1875d916d8b892a82ec130336cbfdf5&mc=true&node=se14.3.135_1143&rgn=div8)